# Drupal 7 Bootstrap page.vars class by content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to modify the page.vars in my bootstrap subtheme to change a class based on content type.

Code as standard in page.vars

```
  elseif (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first']) || !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
       $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-9"';
  }
```

My modified code:

```
elseif (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first']) || !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
 $node = $variables['node'];
     if ($node->type == 'standard') {
         $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-6"';
     }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is putting the class col-sm-6 onto every standard content type page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you're sharing is correct, but you need to tell your sub-theme to read the page.vars.php file.  I just dealt with a similar problem and came up with this solution based on information [found here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2224003).

What you need to do is add a theme function in your sub-theme's template.php something like:

```
function SUB_THEME_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    bootstrap_include($theme, 'theme/system/page.vars.php');
    $hooks = array();
    return $hooks;
}
```

Then you can add *theme/system/page.vars.php* in your sub-theme and any functions in the page.vars.php file will be included in the registry and applied after the bootstrap base theme.  Once you've done that your above code should work as it is.